# Using Python 3.7, obtaining data from Oracle Business Intelligence WSDL

Tags: python, oracle, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a project where I need to query data from Oracle Business Intelligence (OBI) using Python. The OBI API is soap/wsdl. I've been able to list certain details from OBI but have not figured out how to get actual data.

I'm running Windows 10, using Visual Studio Code. Python 3.7.4. Currently using the zeep module but have used suds with the same limitation.

I've tried several different calls but usually get errors due to a type conversion issue or parameters that I'm not sure how to get.

```py
from zeep import Client, Settings
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client(wsdl='http://obi_address:[port]/analytics-ws/saw.dll/wsdl/v12', settings=settings)
SAWSessionService = client.create_service('{urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v12}SAWSessionService','http://obi_address:[port]/analytics-ws/saw.dll?SoapImpl=nQSessionService')
sessionid = SAWSessionService.logon(obi_username,obi_password)

MetadataService = client.create_service('{urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v12}MetadataService','http://obi_address:[port]/analytics-ws/saw.dll?SoapImpl=metadataService')
sa_list=MetadataService.getSubjectAreas(sessionid)
for sa in sa_list:
    sa_tbls= MetadataService.describeSubjectArea(sa.name,'IncludeTables',sessionid)
    print(sa_tbls)
```

So here I get a list of the tables for each subject area, but I'm not sure how to go about querying the data in the tables. Does anyone have any experience with this?

I'm using documentation found here, though not all calls are described.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIEIT/methods.htm#BIEIT237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by getting access to the OBI Oracle database, calling the SQL generated by OBI, and querying for the data in Python, initially using "cx_Oracle" until updated to "[oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb)."